# Scrapy crawler - Enabling Frontera middlewares removes the referer header from response objects

Tags: python, scrapy, frontera

When i enable the following frontera middleware in scrapy

I lose all my referer headers in all my `response` objects

Is there anyway i can preserver the referrer?

The referer is available when i remove the following lines, but i need to enable these frontera middlewares

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES.update({
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerSpiderMiddleware': 1000,
})


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES.update({
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerDownloaderMiddleware': 1000,
})

SCHEDULER = 'frontera.contrib.scrapy.schedulers.frontier.FronteraScheduler'
```

Also, the `referermiddleware` is enabled, i can see it when in the debug log when scrapy starts

**Edit**: This is my entire configuration file contents

```
BOT_NAME = 'crawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['crawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'crawler.spiders'

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36"

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2


DUPEFILTER=True


ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'crawler.pipelines.AllDataPipeline': 300
}


SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {}


RETRY_ENABLED = True
RETRY_TIMES = 5
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 400, 408]
REFERER_ENABLED = True

######################################################################
# Frontera Settings 
#######################################################################


BACKEND = 'frontera.contrib.backends.sqlalchemy.FIFO'
SQLALCHEMYBACKEND_ENGINE = 'sqlite:///frontier.db'


HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = False
REDIRECT_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 20
RETRY_ENABLED = False

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 10
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 2

LOGSTATS_INTERVAL = 10

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {}





SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES.update({
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerSpiderMiddleware': 699,
})


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES.update({
    'frontera.contrib.scrapy.middlewares.schedulers.SchedulerDownloaderMiddleware': 1000,
})

SCHEDULER = 'frontera.contrib.scrapy.schedulers.frontier.FronteraScheduler'
```

Comment: Did you try to add the SchedulerSpiderMiddleware with a value < 700 to your config? For example 699?

Comment: @GHajba Edited the question, added the entire config file.  added the suggested middleware to 699, but the referer is always `None` the referer comes back when i disable the frontera middleware

Answer (score -1):

DupeFilter can't be just True.
You can set like

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = "scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter.RFPDupeFilter"
```

if you want to do requests without dupe filter, you can add `dont_filter=True` kwargs to your `scrapy.Request`

Comment: Can you elaborate so that this is a higher quality answer?